# Android Serversocket does not seem to accept connections on emulators

Tags: android, sockets, client

I've been trying to implement a simple socket communication between two Android emulators but just can't seem to get it.

**My server:**

```
public void run() {     
    if (SERVERIP != null) {
        try {
            serverStatus.setText("My IP: " + SERVERIP);
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6798);
            serverStatus.setText("ServerSocket Created");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            while (true) {   
                serverStatus.setText("waiting for client");
                Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                serverStatus.setText("Connected.");
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                String line = in.readLine();

                serverStatus.setText(line);
                in.close();
                client.close();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else
        serverStatus.setText("Couldn't detect internet connection.");
}
```

**My Client:**

```
try {
    InetAddress ina = InetAddress.getByName("10.0.2.2");
    socket = new Socket(ina, 6789); 
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
    out.println("Hey Server!");
    dispText.setText("sent");
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The Client side goes on to display the message "sent" however the Server does not move beyond "waiting for client" (stuck on the blocking `accept()`).
I've used telnet on my Windows machine to redirect port 6789 to 6798 on the server emulator's console. I've also tried turning off my firewall and the other suggestions posted on the similar questions asked here. Please help as just can't seem to get it and feel like I'm  making a very stupid mistake.

Also, can anyone please tell me how it is possible for the Client to move beyond the Socket creation code line if the Server is still stuck on `accept()`. Or, does it not matter to the client that the Server isn't responding as long as it is listening on the port??

Answer (score 0):

Android emulators are placed behind a virtual firewall/router by design, and cannot see each other, even when they are on the same network. The "[Using Network Redirection](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#redirection)", as well as "Interconnecting Emulator Instances" part of Google's doc on the emulator explains how to communicate with an emulator instance.

As for your last question. Use the empty constructor for socket, and then use the [connect call with a specified timeout](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html#connect%28java.net.SocketAddress,%20int%29).

Comment: I did go through the Android doc. My Server and Client both have IP address as 10.0.2.15, each being on it's own virtual network. That is why the Client connects to 10.0.2.2 (loopback).   I've tried the empty construction socket creation and then using connect but I still get the same problem: Client still displays 'sent' and the Server is stuck.  Please help.